# Fixing a memory leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I've ran Build and Analyze on my XML parsing code and found out the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](http://img.skitch.com/20100221-fmm92e2fbsxfgaih1eqjr1x8sr.jpg))</sub>

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[channelListing addObject:[[channelListingItem copy] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the copy of `channelListingItem`. As you're passing it to the `channelListing`, you can just `autorelease` it as it will be "owned" by that mutable collection.

Answer (score 0):

you need to release it as said, the channelListingItem is retaining it.